# Define Dlib C++ constant matrix

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dlib, compile-time-constant

I found one post about this but it wasn't really relevant. Hence my question: how does one define a Dlib matrix as a global compile-time constant? See attached example.

Thank you..

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dlib/matrix.h"
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

const int n_rows = 2;
const int n_cols = 4;
const matrix <int,n_rows,n_cols> X = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8; 

int main()
{   
  cout << "X: \n" << X << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless the class has a [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) constructor then you can't really do it.

Comment: Please, avoid `using namespace`.

Comment: Thanks you - it doesn't have such a constructor, which explains a lot.

Comment: Actually - it does. As Davis King pointed out, you can use {}-style initialization.